# Raw array construction and access in Haxe

Tags: arrays, memory, haxe

The `std.Array` in Haxe is not a raw array, but rather a managed one - it implements automatic grow and shrink mechanisms, etc. This is great for general use cases, but I need something closer to the metal, because I need greater control over it.

Something like `Foo[] myFoos;` instead of `ArrayList<Foo> myFoos;` in Java.

How do I do this in Haxe?

---

Details:

I tried looking in the implementation of 
[`std.Array`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/Array.hx)
to find this, to no avail - it is interface only. Would it be correct to assume that the actual implementation is in the OCaml compiler implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your platform, native arrays are exposed as [`cpp.NativeArray`](http://api.haxe.org/cpp/NativeArray.html), [`java.NativeArray`](http://api.haxe.org/java/NativeArray.html), [`cs.NativeArray`](http://api.haxe.org/cs/NativeArray.html) etc. If you're compiling to multiple targets it should be straightforward to build an abstract that smooths over the differences between these types.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out NativeArrays! 

I was hoping that there would already be a standard wrapper around the various implementations, and it looks like there already is one (kinda): [`haxe.ds.Vector`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/51a8e693/std/haxe/ds/Vector.hx#L56-L76) ... still not a "raw" array like I asked for, but better than `std.Array` for my purposes.